# JQuery Apply CSS Class to Toggled Element

Tags: jquery, css

How do I apply a class to a bootstrap toggled element?

I have the following:

```
<ul class="my-nav ">
     <li >
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#one" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="one" class="collapsed">
               ...
         </a>
     </li>
     <li >
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#two" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="two" class="collapsed">
               ...
         </a>
     </li>
</ul>

<div class="collapse my-pane" id="one">
     <ul >
          <li ><a href="#">...</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">...</a></li>
     </ul>
</div> 

<div class="collapse my-pane" id="two">
     <ul >
          <li ><a href="#">...</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">...</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

When I toggle link with #one I get the following css applied to it:

```
<li >
     <a data-toggle="one" href="#one" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="one" class="">
               ...
     </a>
</li>
```

Now I want to apply some background colour to it when it's active. How can I use JQuery to apply the following css to the selected `<li>`:

```
.my-nav li.my-nav-selected a {
    background-color: background-color: #dae1f3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need javascript, you can do that with CSS

```
.my-nav li a[aria-expanded="true"]{
    background-color: #dae1f3; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9tt7dgz9/

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can assume that you are using Bootstrap if I'm not wrong. If this is the case you can use the callback functions of Bootstrap itself.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   // do something…
})
```

You can also land on [Bootstrap JS demo  page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

If not Bootstrap then you can try following

```
$('.my-nav li a.collapsed').on('click', function(e){
    $('.my-nav li').removeClass('my-nav-selected');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('my-nav-selected');
});
```

Hope, this would help!

Comment: I am using bootstrap so how would i do it using bootstrap?